# commit only directory and not the files in it

Tags: svn

I am committing the files to SVN using the API available in SVNKit, using the below code

```
ourClientManager.getWCClient().doAdd(subFile, false, false, true, false);
ourClientManager.getCommitClient().doCommit(path, false, comment, false, false);
```

When i commit a new directory, the file in it are automatically committed. (I have set recursive false.) Is there a way to stop that?
 I want to pass a different comment for the new directory committed and the file committed, so i want commit them separately. Please suggest if there is a way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In svn commands, you'd do `svn add --depth=empty mydirectory`

With SVNKit, pass in the EMPTY value for the [SVNDepth](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNDepth.html) parameter, e.g.:

```
doAdd(mydirectory, false, false, false, SVNDepth.EMPTY)
```

Answer (score 1):

ci takes the --depth switch too, like add does, and you don't have to muck with properties.

```
svn add --parents directory_with_WIP/*.pl
svn ci -m 'The new directory' --depth=empty directory_with_WIP
svn ci -m 'First file ready' directory_with_WIP/flibber.pl
```

Comment: ha! This was just the information I needed, so I tried to vote it up, but it's my own answer! Laughing out loud.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Luke works well, but it wont add sub directories inside 'mydirectory', So the svn command will be,

```
svn add -N mydirectory
```

Enter inside 'mydirectory' and execute this command,

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.*'

svn commit -m "Adding directory structure only"
```